# Traversing through directories with mutex and pthreads

Tags: c, directory, pthreads, mutex

My program currently is traversing through directories finding mp3 files. In each thread, I'm finding mp3 files found in each directory. When I find an mp3 file, I'm inserting the file into an array.

Problem: I'm getting different segmentation faults every time I run the program.

I believe my pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock are positioned in the correct area but I don't understand why my program keeps failing. Any help or advice is appreciated!

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *func(void *);

char **data;
int data_length;
char **directories;
int length;
int num = 0;
int directory_accum = 0;
unsigned long i = 0;
struct dirent *entry;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void listFilesRecursively(char *path);

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // INITIALIZE DATA TO NULL
    data = NULL;
    directories = NULL;
        
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Must give a path\n");
        return -1;
    }
            
    // SWITCH CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY TO DIR GIVEN ON COMMAND LINE
    chdir(argv[1]); // JUST ONCE
        
    // DIRECTORY POINTER
    // OPEN THE CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY
    DIR *current = opendir(".");
    //printf("%lx\n", (unsigned long)current);
    
    int directoriessize = 1;
    // read entries and output based on type
    while( (entry = readdir(current)) ) 
    {
        
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) 
        {
            if((strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0)  && (strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0))
            {
                printf("IN MAIN FUNCTION:\n");
                directoriessize++;
                directories = realloc(directories, sizeof(char*) * directoriessize);
                directories[directory_accum] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
                printf("%s is a directory\n", entry->d_name);
                directories[directory_accum] = entry->d_name;
                directory_accum++;
                //listFilesRecursively(entry->d_name);
                printf("\n");   
            }
        } else if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) {
            printf("IN MAIN FUNCTION:\n");
            printf("%s is a regular file\n\n", entry->d_name);
        } else {
            printf("IN MAIN FUNCTION:\n");
            printf("%s is idk\n\n", entry->d_name);
        }
        
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("# of Directories: %d\n\n", directory_accum);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < directory_accum; i++)
    {
        printf("Directories in array: %s\n", directories[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    pthread_t tids[directory_accum];
    // initialize data to NULL
    data = NULL;

    // start all of the threads ( AFTER SEEING HOW MANY DIRECTORIES YOU HAVE)
    // FOR EXAMPLE ONLY START TWO THREADS FOR a AND b in top. c DIRECOTRY WILL BE
    // HELD INSIDE THE b THREAD
    for(i = 0; i < directory_accum; ++i) 
    {
        int err = pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, func, (void**) directories[i]);
        if (err != 0) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "! Couldn't create thread");
        }
    }

    // wait for threads and join them
    for(int i = 0; i < directory_accum; ++i) 
    {
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }

    // print out data
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) 
    {
        printf("%s", data[i]);
        free(data[i]);
    }
    free(data);

    return 0;
}

// THREAD FUNCTION
// RECURSAL TRAVERSAL OF THE DIRECTORIES HAPPEN HERE OR MAYBE IN SECONDAY FUNCTION
//void *func(void *arg) 
void *func(void *arg) 
{
    char *directory = arg;
    
    // critical section : (LOCKS THIS SO ONLY ONE FUNCTION WILL RUN THIS AT THE TIME)
    //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("NEW THREAD\n");
    
    listFilesRecursively(directory);
    
    printf("\n\n");
    
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

void listFilesRecursively(char *basePath)
{
    char path[1000];
    DIR *current = opendir(basePath);

    // Unable to open directory stream
    if (!current)
            return;

        while ((entry = readdir(current)) != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0)
            {
                // Construct new path from our base path
                strcpy(path, basePath);
                strcat(path, "/");
                strcat(path, entry->d_name);
                printf("Path: %s\n", path);

                if(entry->d_type == DT_REG) 
                {
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
                    printf("------------------\n");
                    printf("Writing %s to file\n", entry->d_name);
                    printf("------------------\n");         
                    
                    if(length < (num + 1))
                    {
                        length = num + 1;
                    }
                    
                    data = realloc(data, sizeof(char*) * length);
                    data[num] = entry->d_name;
                    num++;
                    
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
                }
                listFilesRecursively(path);
            }
        }

    closedir(current);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `directories[directory_accum] = entry->d_name;` That's not how you copy a string. You are leaking memory. Whenever you see `var = malloc(..); var = something` that's an error. The functions are quite big - I suggest to split the work in to small manageable functions. `(void**) directories[i]);` is strange - remove the `void**`. `pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
                    printf` - you are locking for printing? I would go with separate lock for printing and separate for memory.  `data[num] = entry->d_name;` that's not how you copy a string. `d_name` is freed when `closedir` is called...

Comment: `char path[1000];` Use `PATH_MAX`. Lately I like suggesting `asprintf`. `advice is appreciated!` Use a debugger - learn how to debug. Compile with all warnings enabled and fix them. Use address sanitizer. Check dynamic leaks with valgrind. Test smaller chunks of your program before starting big. Prefer not to use global variables. Use `struct`s to logically connect variables. Rather do not use VLA. Write function that work on structs to reuse functionality (ie. `data&data_length` and `directories&length` represent an array of strings... and you "push_back" to it).

Comment: I would suggest just using `ftw` or `fts`. Multithreading with filesystem I/O is possibly disadvantageous.